# PySpark KMeans model has negative training cost

Tags: k-means, pyspark

I am fitting a [KMeans model](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans.html#kmeans) for clustering using `cosine` distance measure. After model fitting, when I check the training cost of the model as below,

```
kmeans_model.summary.trainingCost
-1319601.6000525472
```

According to [KMeansModelSummary](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeansSummary.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeansSummary.trainingCost), this metric is supposed to capture the sum of squared distances to the nearest centroid for all points in training dataset.

Can anyone help me understand how would this metric have a negative value if it is a distance metric.